# Why is this the wrong way to interpret a confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval

The General Social Survey (GSS) is a sociological survey used to collect data on demographic characteristics and attitudes of residents of the United States. In 2010, the survey collected responses from over a thousand US residents. The survey is conducted face-to-face with an in-person interview of a randomly-selected sample of adults. One of the questions on the survey is “For how many days during the past 30 days was your mental health, which includes stress, depression, and problems with emotions, not good?”

Based on responses from 1,151 US residents, the survey reported a 95% confidence interval of 3.40 to 4.24 days in 2010. Given this information, which of the following statements would be most appropriate to make regarding the true average number of days of “not good” mental health in 2010 for US residents?

- For all US residents in 2010, based on this 95% confidence interval, we would reject a null hypothesis stating that the true average number of days of “not good” mental health is 5 days.
- For these 1,151 residents in 2010, we are 95% confident that the average  number of days of “not good” mental health is between 3.40 and 4.24 days.
- For all US residents in 2010, there is a 95% probability that the true average number of days of “not good” mental health is between 3.40 and 4.24 days.

Why is the last option not the right way to interpret this confidence interval?

Comment: From the classical/frequentist perspective, the true average is not random: it is fixed but unknown. Hence it does not make sense to ask for the probability that it lies in a certain range; that would require viewing the true average as realized from some underlying probability distribution. (Bayesians, by contrast, do view model parameters as probabilistic.) The answer is (a), but (b) would be good, too, if you made the first phrase the same as the first phrase in (a).